# Rails retuning an array of ids with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

In my controller i'm looking to return an array with 2 conditions attached.

```
parent_ids = StudentGuardian.where(:guardian_id => current_user.school_user.id).pluck(:student_id)

classmodule_ids = SubjectStudent.pluck (:class_id)

@homework = Homework.where("subject in ?", classmodule_ids)
```

So in this case I need to find a student id from a table and then I need to get a class_id from another table.

Then I am trying to display results.

Can I get both in to the one query?

I also tried `@homework = Homework.where("subject in ?", parent_ids, classmodule_ids)`Of course this does not work!

Answer (score 3):

You just want to know if `subject` is in `parent_ids` or `classmodule_ids`?

So can you just merge `parent_ids` and `classmodule_ids` into one array:

```
# you could merge these a bunch of different ways, here's one:
search_ids = (parent_ids + classmodule_ids).uniq
# don't forget the () around ? below
@homework = Homework.where("subject in (?)", search_ids)
```

Or if for some reason you didn't want to combine `parent_ids` and `classmodule_ids`:

```
@homework = Homework.where("subject in (?) OR subject in (?)", parent_ids, classmodule_ids)
```

But all of that would mean `subject` is an id also... Is that the case?